# Sqlalchemy get last X rows in order

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need to get the last X rows from a table, but in order of the ID. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
query = users.select().order_by(users.c.id.desc()).limit(5)

print reversed(conn.execute(query).fetchall() )
```

something like that anyway

Comment: I don't think that that query keeps them in order of ids, it will reverse the ids, so what I ended up doing is reversing the output it gave me.

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me...

```
c=session.query(a).order_by(a.id.desc()).limit(2)
c=c[::-1]
```

This solution is 10 times faster than the python slicing solution proposed by BrendanSimon.

Comment: For core: st = select([tab]).where(tab.c.timestamp <= rts).order_by(tab.c.timestamp.desc()).limit(3) and then do [::-1] to reverse it.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you can prefix the order_by parameter with a '-' to get reverse order.

```
query = users.select().order_by(-users.c.id.desc()).limit(5)
```

Also, I believe you can use python slices as an alternative to limit.

```
query = users.select().order_by(users.c.id.desc())[-5:]

query = users.select().order_by(-users.c.id.desc())[:5]
```

Comment: Apparently using negative indices results in getting all rows and slicing in Python instead of a `LIMIT` sent to SQL.