# order by before group by in sqlalchemy

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

want to get last 2 `name` in my table
for example

```
id    name    price
1     name1   100
2     name2   120
3     name3   100
4     name3   150
5     name3   152
```

i want result become

```sql
name
name3
name2
```

already searched similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469220/sqlalchemy-order-by-before-group-by) but find no answer in SQLalchemy

my try

```py
orders = db.session.query(Table.name).filter(SomeFilter).order_by(Table.id.desc()).group_by(
        Table.name).all()
```

problem is `group_by` and `order_by` in same time have no issue with `limit`

**EDIT2**

`result = session.query(test).order_by(test.i.desc()).with_entities(test.j).distinct(test.j).limit(2)`

get error in postgress too

Comment: use `limit()`, see: [Sqlalchemy get last X rows in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345015/sqlalchemy-get-last-x-rows-in-order)

Comment: want ```group_by``` and ```limit``` if use ```group_by``` ```limit``` not work correctly

Comment: problem is ```order by``` after ```group by``` will sort on aliphatic order i want to sort on updated time

Answer (score 2):

OK, I am (very) new to sqlalchemy (so do not mention the 'lot of' imports at the start of this code ), but see my code:

```
import sqlalchemy

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, String, Integer, MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy import text
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine("sqlite+pysqlite:///test.db", echo=True)

Base = declarative_base()
metadata = MetaData(engine)
class test(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test'
    i = Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
    j = Column(Integer)

with Session(engine) as session:
    session.execute("""CREATE TABLE test(i int primary key,j int)""")
    session.execute("""DELETE FROM test""")
    t1 = test(i=1, j=1)
    session.add(t1)
    session.add(test(i=2,j=5))
    session.add(test(i=3,j=5))
    session.add(test(i=4,j=2))
    session.add(test(i=5,j=2))
    session.add(test(i=6,j=3))
    session.add(test(i=7,j=3))
    session.add(test(i=8,j=3))

    session.commit()
    result = session.query(test).group_by(test.j).order_by(test.j.desc()).limit(2)
    for row in result:
          print(f"I: {row.i}  J: {row.j}")
```

BTW: The `DELETE FROM...` is only needed on second run, when I comment the line with `CREATE TABLE....`

the output is:

```
I: 6  J: 3
I: 4  J: 2
```

EDIT: The items should be sorted on `i` desc. To get that done you can use the following code:

(NOTE: j=1 is changed to j=5, to get the correct result)

```
    subquery = session.query(test).order_by(test.i.desc()).with_entities(test.j).subquery()
    result = session.query(subquery).distinct().limit(2)
    for row in result:
          print(f"J: {row.j}")
```

which, with my sample data, returns:

```
J: 3
J: 2
```

EDIT2:  Better result always arise after posting the code here....

It can be done without subquery:

```
result = session.query(test).order_by(test.i.desc()).with_entities(test.j).distinct(test.j).limit(2)
```

EDIT3:  It appears the postgresql is giving an error (see comments).

the following changes are needed to solve this (with help from [PG::Error: SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693089/pgerror-select-distinct-order-by-expressions-must-appear-in-select-list):

- add `from sqlalchemy import func`
- change `create engine(sqlite...` to `create_engine("postgresql://user:password@localhost/dbname", echo=True,)`
- finally the selection looks like:

```
    result = session.query(test).order_by(func.min(test.i).desc()).with_entities(test.j).group_by(test.j).limit(2)
    for row in result:
          print(f"J: {row.j}")
```

see also (Postgres14): [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=dfa595096785b0ad8a8a797eaaa94e0b)

see also (SQLite): [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=6f25f9135afacb5bc8efb069ba2ef7db)

or the DBFIDDLE's side-by-side: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&rdbms2=postgres_14&fiddle=afd9687da44ec2ce2c66d9e08ee38b18

Comment: this will sort on aliphatic order of name, i want to sort before ```group by``` or sort according id ```desc``` in other word sort on ```id``` then group by ```name```

Comment: Sorry my English fails to understand what you tried to say (I am not a native English speaker)

Comment: change ```j=1``` in your code to ```j=5``` and check result pls, result must be same but code will return 5 and 3

Comment: OK, so you seem to want the result of the last SQL statement in this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=6f25f9135afacb5bc8efb069ba2ef7db)

Comment: Added an EDIT, and an EDIT2.

Comment: still have issue in postgress ```SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions```

Comment: Added EDIT3.   P.S. this question shows that it is **important** to include all the details in the question. ( I know it is hard to share details that are important, but do not look important to the writer of the question.... )